# Append three columns in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

I have three columns in my Calc file

```
A B C
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

i want this as result, another column or A with B and C data

```
A
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Are you open to solutions that use a database such as LibreOffice Base?

Comment: Yes, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new LibreOffice Base file (`File -> New -> Database`).  Press `Next` and then "No, do not register the database."  Then press `Finish` and save the file.

Back in the spreadsheet, select cells A1 through C4.  Drag this selection over to the LO Base window where it says `Tables`.  (It may help to move the windows so that Base is on one side of the screen and Calc is on the other side).  Then check the boxes "Use first line as column names" and "Create new field as primary key," and press `Create`.
[image: copy table]

The resulting table should look like this.

[image: Table1]

Next, go to the `Queries` area and press "Create Query in SQL view."  Enter the following query.

```
select A from "Table1"
union select B from "Table1"
union select C from "Table1"
```

Base complains about this syntax, so go to `Edit -> Run SQL command directly` to make it stop complaining.  Now save and close the query as "Query1".

Finally, drag and drop "Query1" to column E in the spreadsheet.
[image: spreadsheet results]