# Counting the number of unique values in one column while filtering on another column

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I would like to count the number of unique values in one column while filtering on the contents of a second column.

An example:

```
    A   B
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   b   2
4   b   1
5   c   2
6   d   3
7   e   4
```

I need count the unique values from column A where column B contains the values '2' or '3'

The answer in this example should return 4 (Rows 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 but not double counting the value 'a' in rows 1 and 2)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions at https://superuser.com/a/1216718/541756 to move the data into LibreOffice Base, and use the following query.

```
select count(distinct(A))
from "Table1"
where B in (2,3);
```

Running the query produces `4` as expected.